# EntityFramework Core can't update Database "id's not same type"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Hi I'm trying to update database with initial migration, but EFCore is saying that

```
Column 'Clothes.Id' is not the same data type as referencing column 'Photos.ClothId' in foreign key 'FK_Photos_Clothes_ClothId'.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
```

It's weird, because even in created migrations it says that id's are "uniqueidentifier".
The project was stared with Asp.Net.Core2.2 but I recently tried to update it to 3.0. Also EntityFramework packages was udpated to 3.0. Maybe it's some kind of bug? Thanks for help :).

UpMethod =>

```cs
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Clothes",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "NEWID()"),
                    CreatedAt = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "GETDATE()"),
                    LastTimeModified = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "GETDATE()"),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    Price = table.Column<decimal>(type: "decimal(6,2)", nullable: false),
                    BoughtOn = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())"),
                    ClothType = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    Size = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    Color = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    Manufacturer = table.Column<string>(nullable: false),
                    ClothUrl = table.Column<string>(nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Clothes", x => x.Id);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Photos",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "NEWID()"),
                    CreatedAt = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "GETDATE()"),
                    LastTimeModified = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2", nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "GETDATE()"),
                    PhotoUrl = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(max)", nullable: false),
                    ClothId = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(max)", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Photos", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Photos_Clothes_ClothId",
                        column: x => x.ClothId,
                        principalTable: "Clothes",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_Photos_ClothId",
                table: "Photos",
                column: "ClothId",
                unique: true);
        }
```

I'm using fluentApi to provide settings etc.

```cs
 public class WardrobeContext : DbContext
    {
        public WardrobeContext(DbContextOptions<WardrobeContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Cloth> Clothes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Photo> Photos { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ApplyConfiguration(new BaseEntityConfiguration<Cloth>());
            builder.Entity<Cloth>(ConfigureCloth);

            builder.ApplyConfiguration(new BaseEntityConfiguration<Photo>());
            builder.Entity<Photo>(ConfigurePhoto);
        }

        private void ConfigureCloth(EntityTypeBuilder<Cloth> builder)
        {
            builder.Property(cloth => cloth.Name)
                .IsRequired(true);
            builder.Property(cloth => cloth.BoughtOn)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())")
                .HasColumnType("datetime2");
            builder.Property(cloth => cloth.ClothType)
                .IsRequired(true);
            builder.Property(cloth => cloth.ClothUrl)
                .IsRequired(true);
            builder.Property(cloth => cloth.Color)
                .IsRequired(true);
            builder.Property(cloth => cloth.Manufacturer)
                .IsRequired(true);
            builder.Property(cloth => cloth.Price)
                .IsRequired(true)
                .HasColumnType("decimal(6,2)");
            builder.Property(cloth => cloth.Size)
                .IsRequired(true);
            builder.HasOne(cloth => cloth.Photo)
                .WithOne(x => x.Cloth)
                .HasForeignKey<Photo>(photo => photo.ClothId);
        }

        private void ConfigurePhoto(EntityTypeBuilder<Photo> builder)
        {
            builder.Property(photo => photo.PhotoUrl)
                .IsRequired(true)
                .HasColumnType("varchar(max)");
            builder.Property(photo => photo.ClothId)
                .IsRequired(true)
                .HasColumnType("varchar(max)");
            builder.HasIndex(ix => ix.ClothId)
                .IsUnique();
        }
    }
```

```
internal class BaseEntityConfiguration<TEntity> : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity> where TEntity : BaseEntity
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder)
        {
            builder.Property(baseEntity => baseEntity.Id)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("NEWID()")
                .HasColumnType("uniqueidentifier");
            builder.Property(baseEntity => baseEntity.CreatedAt)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("GETDATE()")
                .HasColumnType("datetime2")
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
            builder.Property(baseEntity => baseEntity.LastTimeModified)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("GETDATE()")
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                .HasColumnType("datetime2");
        }
    }
```

Comment: *in created migrations it says that id's are "uniqueidentifier"* -- well, not `Photos.ClothId`.

Comment: `ClothId = table.Column<string>(type: "varchar(max)", nullable: false)` Is that the same type as the GUID used for the PK of `Clothes` table?

Comment: Im sorry. Just didnt notice that one. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The foreign key column type must be the same as the primary key 
type.Change the type of ClothId  column in the photo entity to uniqueidentifier.